# Making a sub-query on query results?

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I unite these two?

This query:

```
SELECT f1.asked_user_id AS friend_id
    FROM friends AS f1 JOIN friends AS f2
    ON f1.asked_user_id = f2.asker_user_id
    AND f1.asker_user_id = f2.asked_user_id
    AND f1.asker_user_id = :user_id
WHERE f1.status = 1 AND f2.status = 1
```

With:

```
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(words_en.word) FROM connections JOIN words_en ON connections.word_id = words_en.id WHERE connections.user_id = friends.friend_id) As friend_words
```

And do yet another join:

```
JOIN users ON friends.friend_id = users.id
```

I've tried few things here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85d6d/36

First query selects two way friends from the table. I get friend_id from that query.
Now I want to know more about this friend_id.
So I want to use this id to do another query that would display all word_ids from connections table by that user, word_ids can be used to get actual words from words_en.
And lastly, I want to get users name_surname from users table.

Comment: Can you be more clear with your question. What is your expected output?

Comment: @SOaddict I'll try. First query selects two way friends from the table. I get friend_id from that query. Now I want to know more about this friend_id. So I want to use this id to do another query that would display all word_ids from connections table by that user, word_ids can be used to get actuall words from words_en. And lastly, I want to get users name_surname from users table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.name_surname,GROUP_CONCAT(Distinct w.word Order by w.word asc) AS words
FROM (
  SELECT f1.asked_user_id AS friend_id,
       f1.created,
       u.name_surname,
       u.avatar
  FROM friends AS f1 
  INNER JOIN friends AS f2 ON f1.asked_user_id = f2.asker_user_id
  INNER JOIN users AS u ON f1.asked_user_id = u.id
       AND f1.asker_user_id = f2.asked_user_id
       AND f1.asker_user_id = 1
  WHERE f1.status = 1 AND f2.status = 1
) a
LEFT JOIN connections c ON c.user_id = a.friend_id 
LEFT JOIN words_en w ON c.word_id = w.id
GROUP BY 1;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b25f8/66)</kbd>

Having your original query, what i did is treat that query as a table (a) and `LEFT JOIN` it with `connections` table. Then, `LEFT JOIN` the `connections` table with the `words_en` table to reach the desired words. This makes it possible to get all users that return from your original query, even when there are no connections/words.

Comment: awesome! just missing name_surname from users table, if I knew how to add yet another join I would... sorry for bother. I will also try to understand what you did, but some parts escape my understanding :{

Comment: Hey, I tested it and it failed, when user has more than 1 friend it returns wrong results... http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b25f8/7

Comment: again, it worked! :) farther tested it and found that if you do f1.asker_user_id = 5 returns NULL NULL. but this user doesn't exist. so there should be no records returns :S

Comment: And if I set f1.asker_user_id = 2 it only returns 1 friend, not both... in reality user 2 has friend 1 and 3 but query returns only 1.

Comment: I'm not sure how that null null is working. About f1.asker_user_id = 2 only returning 1 friend, that is not true. That is returning the words for both of them, but with the distinct w.word it removes the word 1 from user 3.

Comment: AND f1.asker_user_id = 2 should return user1 and user3 with respective words. Original query did this ok, without additional data of words: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b25f8/55 I simply want to get same, but with words for each user. btw, thanks for sticking with me really, mysql is my pain :)

Comment: I fixed it. It was missing the group by (1 means the first column of the select, if you didn't know that). :p

Comment: now it doesn't return anything for other users but for user id 2 it is correct.

Comment: That's what you want right? For the other users you don't want to see null null. The group by removed that.

Comment: There are different issues now. Let explain better. If I put user 1 it returns nothing right now, but it should return 2 because they are mutual friends. If I put 2 it should return 1 and 3 which it correctly does right now. If I put 3 it should return 2 because they have mutual friendship.

Comment: NULL NULL was happening when you would put non existent id in the query. it would return user null, words null. Which is not correct. Yes I agree this problem is gone now, but it introduced new problem, described above.

Comment: That is the a problem due to not having enough connections. I added a connection of (2,2) and it returns it when user_id = 3. Do you want the user to be returned even if they don't have any words?

Comment: Yes, exactly, even if user has no words it should returned.

Comment: see if this is what you want: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b25f8/66 . I replaced the inner joins with left joins. LEFT JOIN returns the records from the table in the left even when there is no match in the table in the right.

Comment: This is what I wanted: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b25f8/66 but thanks for the other query too ! :)

Comment: Well, you made it work :) I purchased sql book from amazon right now, I need to understand better these things, unfortunately I couldn't learn in practice without a book.

Comment: That resource looks great!