# How to select pending friend requests from Database mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

SQL: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f7a0d5/4

Table contains these rows:

```
INSERT INTO `friends` (`asker_user_id`, `asked_user_id`, `status`) VALUES (1,2,1);
INSERT INTO `friends` (`asker_user_id`, `asked_user_id`, `status`) VALUES (2,1,1);
INSERT INTO `friends` (`asker_user_id`, `asked_user_id`, `status`) VALUES (3,2,1);
```

This query selects two way friends of current user:

```
    SELECT f1.asked_user_id AS friend_id
        FROM friends AS f1 JOIN friends AS f2
        ON f1.asked_user_id = f2.asker_user_id
        AND f1.asker_user_id = f2.asked_user_id
    WHERE f1.status = 1 AND f2.status = 1
    AND f1.asker_user_id = 2
```

So it results in 1. Because user 2 has only user 1 as two way friend.

How do I show pending requests for user 2? Where user 2 is asked_user_id?

THis (3,2,1) is a pending request for user 2. Where 3 asked 2 to be friends. And for them to become two way friends new entry will be created wiht (2,3,1).

Comment: What is peding? status different than 1?

Comment: BTW `f1.asker_user_id` should be in the `WHERE` clause. `ON` should only contain relationships between the tables (except in outer joins, where single-table conditions may be needed in some cases).

Comment: @FilipeSilva no pending status is when entry doesn't exist.

Comment: @FilipeSilva (3,2,1) is a pending request for user 2 by user 3.

Comment: For pending requests, you use a left join and look for NULL matches.

Comment: It's essentially the same as `Find rows in table A that don't have a match in table B`, a common SQL idiom. The only difference in your case is that the two tables are the same.

Comment: @Barmar I'm trying it now, thanks!

Comment: @Barmar not working out as expected: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f7a0d5/28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get peding requests with the following:

```sql
SELECT f1.asker_user_id AS friend_id
FROM friends AS f1 
LEFT JOIN friends AS f2
    ON f1.asked_user_id = f2.asker_user_id
    AND f1.asker_user_id = f2.asked_user_id   
WHERE f1.status = 1 AND f2.status IS NULL
AND f1.asked_user_id = 2
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f7a0d5/17)</kbd>

Comment: Can you please help me with this too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774587/making-a-sub-query-on-query-results

Comment: It is me bothering you again :) I'm trying to make same for the pending request user list. The above query works perfectly, but I need info like words and user avatar and surname just like in the other post. I tried it here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f7a0d5/54 I copied left join and IS NULL. In essence f1.asker_user_id = 2 should result in user 3, because that one is pending for user 2.

Comment: You should open a  different question for this. Since you now want different things than your original question, but you are on the right track for sure. You can reference this question in the new one to say it is based on this one. And explain the new requirements

Comment: You are absolutely right! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791301/pending-friend-request-query-for-friends-table-and-grabbing-data-from-other-tabl

Answer (score 0):

is this you looking for ?

this will show users who wants be friend with user 2  , so user 2 have 2 pending requests

```
 SELECT f1.asker_user_id AS friend_id
 FROM friends AS f1 
 WHERE f1.status = 1 
 AND f1.asked_user_id = 2
```

[**demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f7a0d5/27)