# Pending friend request query for friends table and grabbing data from other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

To get pending request for selected user I use:

```
SELECT f1.asker_user_id AS friend_id
FROM friends AS f1 
LEFT JOIN friends AS f2
    ON f1.asked_user_id = f2.asker_user_id
    AND f1.asker_user_id = f2.asked_user_id   
WHERE f1.status = 1 AND f2.status IS NULL
AND f1.asked_user_id = 2
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f7a0d5/65 It correctly returns user 3. VALUES (3,2,1)

But I'd like to get more data about this user 3.

I need `name_surname` and `avatar` from `users` table.
And all `word_id`s of this user from `connections` table, which in return would show `word` from `words_en` based on `word_id`.

Thanks allot!

p.s. I tried this:

```
SELECT a.name_surname,GROUP_CONCAT(Distinct w.word Order by w.word asc) AS words
FROM (
  SELECT f1.asked_user_id AS friend_id,
       f1.created,
       u.name_surname,
       u.avatar
  FROM friends AS f1 
  LEFT JOIN friends AS f2 ON f1.asked_user_id = f2.asker_user_id
  INNER JOIN users AS u ON f1.asked_user_id = u.id
       AND f1.asker_user_id = f2.asked_user_id
  WHERE f1.status = 1 AND f2.status IS NULL
       AND f1.asker_user_id = 2
) a
LEFT JOIN connections c ON c.user_id = a.friend_id 
LEFT JOIN words_en w ON c.word_id = w.id
GROUP BY 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this question and your previous questions, i think you might be looking for something like this:

```
SELECT u.name_surname, 
       u.avatar,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT w.word Order by w.word asc) AS words
FROM users u
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT f1.asker_user_id AS friend_id
    FROM friends AS f1 
    LEFT JOIN friends AS f2
        ON f1.asked_user_id = f2.asker_user_id
        AND f1.asker_user_id = f2.asked_user_id   
    WHERE f1.status = 1 AND f2.status IS NULL
    AND f1.asked_user_id = 2
) a ON a.friend_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN connections c ON u.id = c.user_id
LEFT JOIN words_en w ON w.id = c.word_id
GROUP BY u.id;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27493/10)</kbd>

Comment: What is the difference between this and the way of Linger. They seem to produce same results, but seem completely different.

Comment: This gives the users always, even if they don't have words, and groups  them by name_surname. It then groups them by u.id (i edited from 1 to u.id, since u.id is unique). His query will only give results when they have connections and words.

Answer (score 1):

HERE IS THE [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f7a0d5/94/0) of the below query, which is what i think you are after.

```
SELECT users.name_surname, users.avatar,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT words_en.word Order by words_en.word asc) AS words
FROM 
(
SELECT f1.asker_user_id AS friend_id
    FROM friends AS f1 
    LEFT JOIN friends AS f2
        ON f1.asked_user_id = f2.asker_user_id
        AND f1.asker_user_id = f2.asked_user_id   
    WHERE f1.status = 1 AND f2.status IS NULL
    AND f1.asked_user_id = 2
) AS MainQ
INNER JOIN users ON MainQ.friend_id = users.id
INNER JOIN connections ON users.id = connections.user_id
INNER JOIN words_en ON words_en.id = connections.word_id
```

Comment: **@Red Balloon**, fixed by adding the `GROUP_CONCAT`.